# Integrate zxing code with the application and install in on Android os higher than 1.5

Tags: android

i am working on an application that needs to scan bar codes as a functionality..I have integrated all the code of zxing with my app code and now when i try to install it on my device(OS 1.6) it gives me an "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE" error...

i cant use intents to use the barcode application because that will create a necessity to have zxing installed on the device..i want my application to be standalone..

Please suggest what do i do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same thing you tried to do. I did not have any such error.

Yet, the error mentions ABI, which makes me believe the problem is NDK related. (AFAIK) ZXing doesn't use native code, so you should look at the native code in you application.

Comment: Correct, it has nothing to do with zxing or Android 1.6.

Comment: can you please explain how'd you do that??? because i am not using any native code in my application..so i thought it may be the zxing code. But now you are saying zxing doesnt use any native code.. So how do i compile OR run it on 1.6

Comment: Hmm, looks like a strange error to me then. I can only help you with more details about your code (possibly the code itself). I don't know how to help otherwise, as I never encountered this error.

Comment: thanks man.. solved the issue...i was also adding test data and libraries to the code and android os is taking them as native code.. as soon as i remove those from the code, it started working fine...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I have no native code in my application.  How exactly was android mistaking data or libraries as native code?  Is this really related to zxing integration because I too have integrated with zxing, but there is no native code?  Can you explain how including those libraries caused this problem?